# Multiple requests going in case of request close (Fresco + OkHttp)

Tags: android, okhttp, fresco

I am using Fresco with OkHttp 2.7.4. By default the image request from the previous activity won't get canceled when we switch to a new activity. This makes the new activity load slower as previous requests are still running. So I am closing the all the image requests in `onStop()` of my activity based on `tag`.

The request are getting closed, all good...But the requests are fired again to download the images from the previous activity. It is retrying to download the images again. I have `setRetryOnConnectionFailure(false)`.

Not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Not sure if Fresco is triggering new requests on cancel. I didn't find any configuration option with Fresco.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: This will be easier to answer if you can identify whether or not Fresco is triggering the retries.

Comment: Can you follow the "Investigating issues with logcat" steps in http://frescolib.org/docs/troubleshooting.html? Then we can see whether the requests are coming from Fresco or not.